# python | Ошибка при запросе!

Tags: python, requests

```
def main(target):
    headers = {"headers": str(linecache.getline("agents.txt", random.randrange(1, 1000)))}
    b = requests.get(str(target), headers = headers)

main("https://2ip.ru/")
```

Ошибка:

> ValueError: Invalid header value b'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4;
> BNTV600 Build/IMM76L) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/42.0.2311.111 Safari/537.36\n'

Comment: мне кажется, что `"headers": ` в словаре `headers` лишнее. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606260/12785139

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае нужно передавать словарь с явным заголовком `User-Agent`, а не `headers` с `User-Agent`. Пример ниже:

```
import requests


def main(target):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; BNTV600 Build/IMM76L) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.111 Safari/537.36'}
    b = requests.get(target, headers = headers)


main("https://2ip.ru/")
```

Comment: не помогло, что делать?

Comment: Я предварительно проверил этот код. Все работает. Можно посмотреть на ошибку? И что у Вас лежит в `str(linecache.getline("agents.txt", random.randrange(1, 1000)))`

Comment: там лежат юзер агенты, ошибка такая же

Comment: Давайте смотреть, что не так у Вас в импортированном списке `User-Agent` из файла `txt`. Рабочий колаб с моим рабочим примером по ссылке https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MfHUO4nUBtsxVaRIHHAtQuRiMMkxq4yP?usp=sharing Там выводится подставляемый `User-Agent` и первые 200 символов ответа.

Comment: Работает, но как только я беру значение с файла появляется ошибка, вот сам файл https://dropmefiles.com/Qw1xA